# Laravel - controller handle multiple models

Tags: laravel

I'm starting with Laravel. I have `LinksController` that handle my links table (CRUD). I want to use this table to store all the links from my app.

I have two tables:

- tutorials
- posts

LinksController.php

```
public function store(Request $request, Tutorial $tutorial) {

    $link = new Link;
    $link->user_id = auth()->user()->id;
    $link->source_id = $tutorial->id;
    $link->link = $request->link;
    $link->save();
}
```

This works fine. Now I was trying to save posts links and I noticed my route model binding can use only one Model.

Routes:

```
tutorials/{tutorial}/links
posts/{post}/links
```

If I change `Tutorial $tutorial` for `Post $post` it will work for posts but not for tutorials.

I read about Polymorphic Relationships but I'm not sure how to pass different models to my `LinksController`.

Should I use something like this in my LinksController.php:

```
private $model;

public function __construct(Request $request) {
    // if route a
    //     $this->model = Tutorial::class;
    // else
    //     $this->model = Post::class;
}
```

I know that I can use hidden input to pass model, but I don't really want to do that.

**Edit**:
Other solutions that come to my mind would be Explicit Binding:

RouteServiceProvider.php

```
Route::model('tutorial', \App\Tutorial::class);
Route::model('post', \App\Post::class);
```

And then in my `LinksController` store method:

```
public function store(Request $request, Model $model) {
```

Do you think this would be a good approach? In this case, the first parameter from the route should always be a variable that is present in my `RouteServiceProvider`.

Is there any better and more elegant approach to my problem?

Comment: So just so I understand, the source_id field in the link model relates to the ID of the post or tutorial?

Comment: @Mike Yes, it will work like Polymorphic fields, for example like commentable_id. I think I will have to change tables to use Polymorphic Relationships. But currently, I'm not sure how to pass a different model to LinksController.

Answer (score 1):

You should add a source_type field to your link model for the polymorphic relationship.

```
$link->source_type = "tutorial" or "post"
```

The route may be something like:

```
Route::post('/{sourceType}/{sourceTypeId}/links', 'LinksController@store')->where(['sourceType' => 'posts|tutorials', 'sourceTypeId' => '[0-9]+']);
```

Then in your controller

```
public function store(Request $request, string $sourceType, int $sourceTypeId) {
    if ($sourceType == 'posts') {
        $source = Post::findOrFail($sourceTypeId);
    } elseif ($sourceType == 'tutorials') {
       $source = Tutorial:findOrFail($sourceTypeId);
    }

    $link = new Link;
    $link->user_id = auth()->user()->id;
    $link->source_id = $source->id;
    $link->source_type = substr($sourceType, 0, -1);
    $link->link = $request->link;
    $link->save();
}
```

I never used polymorphic relationships but this is something I may do.

Comment: Hi @Mike, thank you for your answer. This is the idea I had in my mind (Polymorphic Relationships) but I want to avoid to share my models with users, by that I mean, avoid using hidden inputs in request and model pass by URI. I'm looking for a way to distinct models in my controller without sending models names in the request. I think I can check URI route to see where it points and set model based on that, but it seems not elegant to me.

Comment: Ok yeah I think you can also just create two separate routes with two separate store functions and do regular route model binding. Not sure what the best solution is here either

Comment: Yea, but that will duplicate my code. I updated my post with other solution that might work, Explicit Binding.